# How to find the index of an object in a list of objects given two attributes?

Tags: python, mysql, sql

```
def delete_entry(self,Order_ID, Item_ID):
    """Delete an Item_QtyBookEntry identified by Item_ID"""


    self.d.execute("""Delete from ordered_items Where Order_ID = %s AND Item_ID=%s """
                       ,(Order_ID,Item_ID))
    self.order_entries.remove(x)
```

`self.order_entries` is a list of `orderItemEntry` objects.. given the Order ID and Item ID I need to get the index of the object that has both values to set in x in order to permanently remove the item from the list. before or after the sql query has been executed

this is just part of the entire object and it's init class... but that's where the list is initialized

```
class OrderItem(object):
    """Customer will hold ItemEntry objects"""
    def __init__(self):
        # Initialize our entries list
        self.order_entries = []
```

Comment: how is order_entries defined?

Comment: There's no simple random access by object attributes unless you set up a mapping type - I don't see how you can do better than iterating through your list comparing the attributes until you find the index you need.

Comment: definition of the list added

Comment: Depending on what version of Python you're on and your exact needs, you might consider using an OrderedDict instead of a list, with the tuple of your order ID and item ID as the key.  You could then del the appropriate item by its tuple key rather than an index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so you just want to remove the record you deleted from the database from your list?

```
self.order_entries = [x for x in self.order_entries
                      if x.Order_ID != Order_ID or x.Item_ID != Item_ID]
```

instead of `self.order_entries.remove(x)`

Comment: hmmmm so this particular snippet is to be placed in the delete_entry function?

Comment: @SeanPerez yes, instead of your other remove from list logic

Comment: okay. maybe something's wrong with my SQL statement........... but it apparently leaves ghost data in the database. while removed from the list which is my basis for adding items to the list in the orders... the sql data itself still exists.... hmmmm

Comment: @SeanPerez sorry, fixed should be `!= or !=` instead of `!= and !=` (failed de morgans in my head)

Comment: actually I confirmed the and version works in removing the actual item from the list... thing is the sql query isn't executing properly... rather it never executes. dunno why